# PowerShell: How to get a list of the top biggest files (of a certain type)?

Tags: powershell, filesystems, sort

Getting the biggest file list might look like

```
gci -r|sort -descending -property length | select -first 10 name, length
```

How can I add a specific filetype selection , like ascii or formated log/json/yaml files?

And an option about selecting them only over 30days age might be also a good idea.

My goal is to accumulate filters:

- only work on text files (ignore any other)
- sort them by size
- optional : sort to keep only the more than 30days old ones
- keep & list the 10 biggest ones.

I can compare that need to  that linux command line that feet all of my needs :

```
find . -type f -ctime +30 ! -executable -exec file {} + | grep -i ASCII | du -ah | sort -rh | head -10
```

Comment: how do you determine what files you want to select?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I think that's his question, he wants to only output text files. e.g no picture files like .png etc. I could be wrong though

Comment: @SimonS - without something like the extension ... you are left with opening each file and reading the 1st few chars/bytes. that would be horribly slow ... [*frown*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey jup, agree

Comment: Yes This is exactly the problem ; finding only that kind of files. (no data/bin files) , just like `file somefile` command in linux is able to say it is ascii/formated text/or binary as a test on command line

Comment: @francoisP - the only built in way to find out what kind of file you are looking at is via the extension. if you cannot use that, then you need to use one of the "read some part of the file" techniques and test that data. you can use ... `Get-Content`, the `ReadFile()` variants, external utils, and lots of other methods to open the file & read part of it. unfortunately that still requires you to decide if the read-in stuff is binary data or not. i cannot think of any truly reliable way to do that. [*blush*]

Comment: you mean I should to it with 2/3 separated steps in a script ?  if so why not, the idea is very good? But how powershell script works how to structure it ?

Answer (score 0):

someone gave me a solution to work around

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date
# fill the list of binary filetypes that are most likely found
$binaries = '*.exe', '*.bin', '*.png', '*.gif', '*.jpg', '*.dll'  # I will complete here known extensions 

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Exclude $binaries | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate} | 
    Sort-Object Length -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 10 | 
    Select-Object Name, Length
```

this looks good, to work around